# How to implement row-wise versioning using mysql + java?

Tags: java, database, database-versioning

Lets say for an example we have a table called student  (sID is the primary key, isValid=1 means the row is valid and 0 is invalid for the moment)

```
sId    sName   gpa   isValid 
1      Tom      3.0    1
2      Hanks    3.5    1
```

now let's assume that I have updated Tom's values. but still I want to save the previous values.

```
sId    sName   gpa   isValid 
1      Tom      3.0    0
2      Hanks    3.5    1 
1      Tom      3.6    1
```

Now the Toms values has changes. nut his previous values haven't permanently deleted.

how can I implement this is there a plugin or something?. The problem is that primary key is occurring more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change database design.

Keep in `sId,sName` and any other field(if required) in `student` table which will be parent table.
Create another table like `student_academic` with `sId` as foreign key of student table along with `gpa, isvalid` fields.

For each student values changes insert new transcation entry. 
This also ensures database `Normalization`  and will fulfill your need.

Comment: I'm with this solution. In parent table you put the ID and the non changing values. In the linked table you can put the changing values and just indicate with a flag which one is active (the isValid column you mentioned). No need for a specific library here, plain SQL.

Comment: That's not the solution required.. you are saying that in your answer student table becomes a static table? What if I change student name and want to track that change also?.. Can't I solve this using the "student" table only?... because I think I won't be able to change the structure of the database.

Comment: @Ashan : You haven't mentioned about that. Then in that case you need to add an extra id field which will be NULL for first entry. When you change the data, add new entry but also add previous "sId" in that id field.

Comment: @Mishra Sorry about that mate. then how can I track the changes for a single record. Since there will be more than one row for a particular sID. I can use a sequence-Id field to track the change sequence for a particular record.

Answer (score 0):

I dont feel the need for any plugin here, I would have done something like this:

1. Make your sID autoincrement
2. For every insert, get the last version (sId - 1) and mark it as isValid = 0

I assume you are using jdbc

Comment: No the primary key value can't be change. Since I want to track all the changes for that particular record along with the time.

Comment: definition of primary key is to be unique so it should definitely change, you need another column like record_id(this will be same across all version maintaining your version)